# Automating Xcode Organizer Distribute?

Tags: xcode, archive, ipa, distribute

We have a vendor developing an iOS application for us.  They are providing .xcarchive files of the builds for us.  We have been using the Xcode "Organizer" window to distribute builds as .ipa files.  This is a fairly minor task but it's tedious and repetitive.

I've seen many examples of using xcrun to generate a .ipa file but is it possible to automate this part?